# Event loop is not stopped after calling stop() method using python asyncio module

Tags: python, python-asyncio, event-loop

I have written the following code:

```
import asyncio
import time
from threading import Thread
from threading import Timer

async def myCouroutine():
    time.sleep(3)

dbAccessLoop = None

def stopEventLoop():
    dbAccessLoop.stop()

def eventLoopThreadMain():
    global dbAccessLoop
    try:
        dbAccessLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        dbAccessLoop.run_forever()
    finally:
        dbAccessLoop.close()

def main():
    thread = Thread(target = eventLoopThreadMain)
    thread.start()

    stopLoopTimer = Timer(3, stopEventLoop)
    stopLoopTimer.start()

    while dbAccessLoop is not None and dbAccessLoop.is_running():
        dbAccessLoop.call_soon_threadsafe(asyncio.ensure_future, myCouroutine())
        break

    thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program creates new event loop, starts it, runs coroutine (doing some work) and then after some time using timer it stops the loop. I expect that after calling stop() method dbAccessLoop.run_forever() will give execution back, but that is not happening.

Do I missed something here? My guess is that stop() method is not thread safe but I do not see any errors in the console. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a hole at least in the setting of the `dbAccessLoop`.

```
main -> thread: start
main -> while: dbAccessLoop is None => bailout
thread -> dbAccessLoop = whatever
```

Also, https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-never-awaited-coroutines tells me that the coroutine `myCoroutine` might not be scheduled.  But that's another problem.

And apart from *that*, indeed "Almost all asyncio objects are not thread safe, which is typically not a problem unless there is code that works with them from outside of a Task or a callback." (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading), so the code should call the `stop` in the eventloop's thread using `dbAccessLoop.call_soon_threadsafe(dbAccessLoop.stop)`.

Comment: Thanks, calling it on the thread of main loop fixes the problem, but what should I change in the code to be fine with everything? Did not get about 3-seconds. Could you please explain?

Comment: I misread: I didn't realize there was a `break` in the `while` loop.  But then again - if it only runs once, why not replace it with an `if`?  And if an `if` is needed, something must be wrong with the program logic.

I think the question you should ask is "How do I run an event loop in another thread?"